# How to Change a Box's dimensions/size after creation?

Tags: javascript, three.js

One can easily create a `THREE.BoxGeometry` where you have to pass arguments when creating as three separated arguments for width, height, and depth.

I would like to create any and all `THREE[types]()` with no parameters and set the values after that.

Is there a way to set the dimensions/size of the box geometry after creation (possibly buried in a Mesh already too)? other then scaling etc.

I couldn't find this in the documentation if so, otherwise maybe a major feature request if not a bug there. Any thoughts on how to classify this? maybe just a documentation change.

Comment: take a look at the BoxGeometry at and open the controls to modify it. http://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Reference/Extras.Geometries/BoxGeometry

Comment: What is the problem with using scaling?

Comment: @Wilt well scaling won't let you update all aspects of a geometry such as the number of segments for example. Technically it only creates the illusion of an updated geometry. This is especially noticeable when working with non cube geometries like cylinders or spheres.

Comment: @JacobPhilpott Thanks for your explanation, that totally makes sense. I just wondered since the OP was about a box geometry and in such case those arguments don't really apply.

Comment: @Wilt my pleasure, if your interested you can see my recently posted answer for more details.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to scale a mesh, you have two choices: scale the mesh

```
mesh.scale.set( x, y, z );
```

or scale the mesh's geometry

```
mesh.geometry.scale( x, y, z );
```

The first method modifies the mesh's matrix transform.

The second method modifies the vertices of the geometry.

Look at the source code so you understand what each scale method is doing.

three.js r.73

Comment: Okay I was afraid of that. Would another solution be to load JSON with a JSON loader or something like that?

Comment: Thanks for the scaling option details.

Comment: This is the answer to the question in your original post.

Comment: Technically, scaling only creates the illusion of an updated geometry. I would say a better approach would be geometry reassignment. For more details see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you instantiate a `BoxGeometry` object, or any other geometry for that matter, the vertices and such buffers are created on the spot using the parameters provided. As such, it is not possible to simply change a property of the geometry and have the vertices update; the entire object must be re-instantiated.

You will need to create your geometries as you have the parameters for them available. You can however create meshes without geometries, add them to a scene, and update the mesh's `geometry` property once you have enough information to instantiate the object. If not that, you could also set a default value at first and then scale to reach your target.

Comment: **"You can however create meshes without geometries, add them to a scene, and update the mesh's geometry property once you have enough information..."** this hits the nail on the head! For details on how to achieve this see my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Technically, scaling only creates the illusion of an updated geometry and the question did say *(other then scaling)*. So, I would say a better approach would be to reassign the geometry property of your mesh to a new geometry.

```js
mesh.geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(newSize, newSize, newSize)
```

**With this approach you can update any aspect of the geometry including width segments for example.** This is especially useful when working with non box geometries like cylinders or spheres.

Here is a full working example using this approach:

```js
let size = 10
let newSize = 20

// Create a blank geometry and make a mesh from it.
let geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry()
let material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial()
let mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)

// Adding this mesh to the scene won't display anything because ...
// the geometry has no parameters yet.
scene.add(mesh)

// Unless you intend to reuse your old geometry dispose of it...
// this will significantly reduce memory footprint.
mesh.geometry.dispose()

// Update the mesh geometry to a new geometry with whatever parameters you desire.
// You will now see these changes reflected in the scene.
mesh.geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(size, size, size)

// You can update the geometry as many times as you like.
// This can be done before or after adding the mesh to the scene.
mesh.geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(newSize, newSize, newSize)
```

Comment: This answer is misleading. `geometry.dispose()` is necessary when assigning a new geometry after it has been rendered. three.js r.138.

Comment: @WestLangley I believe it depends on the version your using, either way it's only the  difference of one line of code. I will update my answer to include your advice. Thanks!

Comment: That is not true.  See https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/How-to-dispose-of-objects. You can learn from that and correct your answer. Also, if you want, you can type `renderer.info` into the console and see what happens if you fail to dispose of your geometry properly.

Comment: @WestLangley that's a really helpful link, thanks for sharing! I will update my answer shortly. Look like using `geometry.dispose()` isn't **necessary** but will significantly reduce the memory footprint, so it's definitely best practice!

Comment: It is mandatory. It is the app's responsibility to properly dispose of geometries, textures, and materials that are no longer used. See https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/23773#issuecomment-1076188891.